# Frequency count aggregation of nested elements in elastic search returning zero results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

i am trying to make an aggregation query to count the number of elements in a nested on elastic search. Here is part of the mapping:

```
 {
  "news" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "properties" : {
        "categories" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "categoryId" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "slug" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the query i did:

```
{   
    "size": 0,
    "aggs":{
        "categories_count":{
            "terms": {
                "field":"categories.slug.keyword",
                "size": 100
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the result i am getting:

```
{
    "took": 8,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 22,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "categories_count": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what i am trying to achieve:
say that there are two documents:

doc 1 categories:

```
"categories" : [
      {
        "categoryId" : "aaaaffff",
        "name" : "Category 1",
        "slug" : "category-1",
      },
      {
        "categoryId" : "aaaafffd",
        "name" : "Category 2",
        "slug" : "category-2",
      },
      {
        "categoryId" : "aaaafffc",
        "name" : "Category 3",
        "slug" : "category-3",
      }
    ],
```

Doc 2 categories:

```
"categories" : [
          {
            "categoryId" : "aaaafffd",
            "name" : "Category 2",
            "slug" : "category-2",
          },
          {
            "categoryId" : "aaaafffc",
            "name" : "Category 3",
            "slug" : "category-3",
          },
          {
            "categoryId" : "aaaafffb",
            "name" : "Category 4",
            "slug" : "category-4",
          },
          {
            "categoryId" : "aaaafffe",
            "name" : "Category 5",
            "slug" : "category-5",
          },
        ],
```

Output should be something similar to this:

```
{
    {
        "categoryId": "aaaaffff",
        "name": "Category 1",
        "slug": "category-1",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "aaaafffd",
        "name": "Category 2",
        "slug": "category-2",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "aaaafffc",
        "name": "Category 3",
        "slug": "category-3",
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "aaaafffb",
        "name": "Category 4",
        "slug": "category-4",
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "categoryId": "aaaafffe",
        "name": "Category 5",
        "slug": "category-5",
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Is there any query that can achieve that? thank you in advance. Also is it possible without changing the mapping? because i cannot change the mapping (its from management).

Answer (score 0):

`terms aggregation` should be a field of type `keyword` or any other data type suitable for bucket aggregations. In order to use it with `text` you will need to enable `fielddata`.

To know more refer this official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Adding working example with index mapping and search query

**Mapping**

```
"mappings" : {
  "dynamic" : "false",
  "properties" : {
    "categories" : {
      "type" : "nested",
      "properties" : {
        "categoryId" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "slug" : {
          "type" : "keyword"    <-- change data type to keyword
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query**

```
    {
    "aggs": {
        "count": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "categories"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "categories_count": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "categories.slug"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Search Result:**

```
    "aggregations": {
    "count": {
      "doc_count": 7,
      "categories_count": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "category-2",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "category-3",
            "doc_count": 2
          },
          {
            "key": "category-1",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "category-4",
            "doc_count": 1
          },
          {
            "key": "category-5",
            "doc_count": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am aware of the keyword solution. Unfortunately, it seems that the mapping is from upper management so i can't change it. Is there a way without changing it to keyword? also, what about displaying the other fields inside the buckets? i want to also display the name and the CategoryId.